# Symbol lookup error while using tesseract-ocr

Tags: tesseract

I've been working with Tesseract 4.0.0 for the last two months. I used the ppa by alexander pozdnyakov to install it.

```
"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr"
```

But today when i try to run anything on tesseract i am getting error

```
"tesseract: symbol lookup error: tesseract: undefined symbol:_ZN9tesseract19TessLSTMBOXRendererC1EPKc ".
```

I referred  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464159/symbol-lookup-error-while-using-tesseract) but it's not solved my problem.  My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. I tried reinstalling Tesseract 4, and reinstalled the dependencies as well, but this doesnt seem to help. Even running

```
tesseract --version
```

gives the same error.
Tesseract 3 runs fine. I did run the inbuilt software updater today, but I don't know what that would break. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need reinstall it properly.

you need to autoremove tesseract first by using this cmd:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove tesseract-ocr
```

Now, install your required packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr
```

Finally, install tesseract:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Or After autoremove just git clone following link:

```
git clone https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract.git
cd tesseract
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```